# setting up python2.7 and scikit-learn in sublime text 2

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext2, scikit-learn

I'm on OS X and installed Python 2.7 using Macports and consecutively added numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn using Pip. Pip dumps all of those into the following path:

```
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages'
```

which is also in my sys.path. I'm now trying to make this Python interpreter work in Sublime text 2. Using the default interpreter, sublime throws an error:

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

Numpy and scipy are fine (presumably because they come with the preinstalled Python), but scikit-learn cannot be imported. So I reckoned Sublime's not using the interpreter that Macports and Pip are installing to. I tried setting up a new build system that links to the right path:

```
{
"path": "$PATH:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/",
"cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
"env": {},
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
```

}

However, switching to the new build system and running the import throws the same error. Opening Python in the shell and importing sklearn works like a charm.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Have you tried to install sklearn via "sudo pip install" to make it avaliable in whole system?

Comment: yes, but scikit-learn is already available in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages